# Get data of a single user from JSON in flutter

Tags: php, json, dart

I am trying to display the data of a single user on flutter app from JSON. I created the JSON object in a PHP file.

Here is my JSON output:
[image: Here is my JSON output:]

And here is my dart code where I decode the JSON

```
Future ReadData() async {
    var url = "SOME URL";
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
      print(data);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    calendarSelectedDay = DateTimeRange(
      start: DateTime.now().startOfDay,
      end: DateTime.now().endOfDay,
    );
  }

  getData() async {
    await ReadData();
  }
```

Now, how can I display specific element from JSON? for example if I want to display 'carbs' as a text

```
Text(
                                      data,
                                      style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                          .bodyText1
                                          .override(
                                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                            color: Color(0xFF646464),
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                          ),
                                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

With that code you can get “carbs” from object:

```
print(data[‘carbs’]);
```

Better you can create a class and parse json to class instead of jsonDecode